# Formal Proof using replacement rules and inference laws

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

> Justify each step of the formal proof using inference laws and replacement rules. We know that $ (p \to\ q) \land\ (p \to\ r) =  p \to\ (q \land\ r) $

$1.$ $ p \to\ q   $         $ \mathbf{(premise)}\ $

$2.$ $ q \to\ \overline{r}\    $ $ \mathbf{(premise)}\ $

$3.$ $ p \to\ r   $ $ \mathbf{(premise)}\ $

$4.$ $ \overline{q}\ \lor\ \overline{r}   $  $ \mathbf{(2. Implication )}\ $

$5.$ $ (\overline{q \land\ r})   $  $ \mathbf{(4. DeMorgan)}\ $

$6.$ $ (p \to\ q) \land\ (p \to\ r)   $ $ \mathbf{(?)}\ $

$7.$ $ p \to\ (q \land\ r)   $ $ \mathbf{(6. EquivalenceFromQuestion)}\ $

$8.$ $ \overline{p}\   $ $ \mathbf{(?)}\ $

It's probably very obvious but I am struggling to fill in the steps that are represented by ?'s and am really not sure what I am missing. Any insight would be great thanks.

Comment: 1,3 [Conjunction introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_introduction).

Comment: 5, 7 [Modus tollens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens).